# Implementing friend (available in C++) functionality in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, serialization

Ok, let's leave the debate of whether friendship breaks encapsulation, and actually try elegantly come up with a coherent design.  It is a two fold function:

1) General question on how to implement:

```
  public class A 
   {
      friend class B;
   }
```

2) Why do I need this functionality?  Some of my classes implement `ISerializable` interface. However, I want to make `ISerializable` methods  protected in the Derived class so that I don't expose them to a client (as well as in the documentation). However, internal classes should be able to access them. What is the General way to solve this problem in C#?

Note: I am using friendship as defined in the current C++ standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the `InternalsVisibleTo` stuff to one side, you only have two choices when it comes to implementing interfaces:

- Implement them with public methods
- Implement them using explicit interface implementation

In both cases anyone can call the methods, but using explicit interface implementation you can only call the methods "via" an interface expression (e.g. you could cast a variable of the actual type to the `ISerializable`).

There's no such concept as "internally" implementing an interface.

Comment: These were my thoughts to... but for the sake of argument, what happens if you try to mark an interface implementation method as internal?

Comment: It will no longer implement the interface and you'll get a compile-time error. Not sure why my answer got downvoted though, given that it's actually addressing the question...

Comment: Jon, you solved first part of the question -- this will in fact, prevent a client from calling the method. The second part: I  want this method to NOT be public, else doxygen will export it to documentation, thus confusing users of the API. I gave you an up-vote

Answer (score 4):

C# has the `internal` keyword, so that other types in the same assembly see the types marked internal.  Additionally, you can add [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to the assembly to allow types outside of the assembly to see that assembly's internal members.

Comment: please provide an example of that. The goal of the design is to make sure that CLIENT knows nothing of the existence of this method.

Comment: The client can always use reflection to discover any methods.

Answer (score 4):

If the classes are in the same assembly you can use [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(VS.80).aspx). If they're in different assemblies you can use the [friend assembly attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(VS.80).aspx) members are public within the current .dll and private externally. Additionally, you can expose them to external .dll's by using the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have several solutions, that all revolve around using a private singleton instance as a "key" to prove that the caller is who they say they are.

Solution 1: friend class is a singleton

```
public class A
{
  private underwear myUnderwear;

  public ChangeUnderwear(B friend, underwear newUnderwear) 
  {
    if (friend == null) return;
    myUnderwear = newUnderwear
  }
}

public sealed class B
{
  private B() {};
  private B inst;
  private MessWithA(A a)
  {
    a.ChangeUnderwear(this, new Thong());
  }
}
```

Does anyone see any flaw there?  That technique would work for when you have a Foo class and a FooManager singleton.

Solution 2:
If the friend is not a singleton, I guess you could use the same idea of hiding construction and hiding all instances:

```
interface IB
{ ... }

public sealed class B : IB
{
  private B() {};
  public IB CreateB()
  {
    return (IB)new B();
  }
  private MessWithA(A a)
  {
    a.ChangeUnderwear(this, new Thong());
  }
}
```

But now you now you need some way to prevent an enemy from simply casting IB to a B, and then impersonating a B to access A's friend only members.  Any ideas?

Solution 3: the singleton class lets it's instance be owned by the first caller who requests it.  The friend class tries to grab the instance on startup, and throws a tantrum if someone else grabs it first

```
public class A
{
  private underwear myUnderwear;

  public ChangeUnderwear(B.IdCard friend, underwear newUnderwear) 
  {
    if (friend == null) return;
    myUnderwear = newUnderwear
  }
}

public class B
{
  public sealed class IdCard
  {
    private IdCard() {};
    private static bool created = false;
    public IDCard GetId()
    {
      if (created) throw new Exception("Why are two people asking for the same ID?!?");
      created = true;
      return new IDCard();
    }
  }

  private static IdCard id;

  static B()
  {
    id = IDCard.CreateId();
    if (id == false) throw new Tantrum("Panic: Someone stole my ID card before I could grab it");
  }

  private void MessWithA(A a)
  {
    a.ChangeUnderwear(id, new Thong());
  }
}
```